# How to save a value generated in middle of a MATLAB simulink operation

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have MATLAB Simulink model running successfully. In this model, a function runs code to do the operation. The function code generates a value during the operation. I want to save this value and use at successive operations. 
[image]

In above screen shot, Icur_in and Icur_ou are input and output of the function. In fact both refer to same value. I am using memory function to hold the value for next operation. Up to this point is fine. But the value keeps on changing.

My present code is:

```
Function [Icur_ou] =  fun(Icur_in)

Icur_ou = Icur_in;
if somecondition
   Icur_ou = I_s; 
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about what your problem is, since you state: *"Up to this point is fine."* And also your model looks fine to me, but nevertheless I found [this link](https://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2014/08/06/how-do-you-hold-the-value-of-a-signal/), which seems to be about the same problem. Besides the suggested solutions, I also liked the first two comments about [persistent](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables, which I think could maybe also help you depending on the sample time of your model (see comments in the link).

In this case, you would not need the memory block, but instead you'd have to make your `Icur_` variable `persistent`, so that it stays in memory between function calls. Similar to this:

```
Function [Icur_ou] =  fun(Icur_in)

persistent Icur_ou = Icur_in;
if somecondition
   Icur_ou = I_s; 
end

end
```